# Удалить аудио в процессе проигрывания

Tags: javascript

Необходимо удалить аудио в процессе проигрывание. Ок, из документа удаляю, а проигрывание продолжается. Тогда поступаю так

```
this.audio.pause();
this.audio.remove();
```

Что та мне подсказывает, что это не совсем верно. Возможно можно удалить аудио из html документа так, чтобы и проигрывание остановилось? То есть не за 2 операции это выполнять, а за одну?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не так у вас, как вы можете видеть по примеру, аудио перестаёт воспроизводиться после удаления элемента:

```js
let aud = document.querySelector('audio')

aud.volume = .5

setTimeout(() => {
  aud.remove()
}, 5e3)
```

```html
<audio src="https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/download/mixkit-crickets-and-insects-in-the-wild-ambience-39.wav" autoplay controls></audio>
```